# how to get a div command structured result in virustotal api v2 for php?

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, curl

i am doing one project in [virustotal api v2](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/) and i am downloading virustotalapiV2 from this website http://www.ab-weblog.com/en/php-script-for-accessing-virustotal-api-version-2-0/.i have my public key and other things also in my system i am using wamp server with curl.virustotal api v2 is works fine it is get the url and passed correctly but the result part is display like this

```
stdClass Object(
[permalink] => https://www.virustotal.com/url/dd014af5ed6b38d9130e3f466f850e46d21b951199d53a18ef29ee9341614eaf/analysis/1370899172/
[url] => http://www.google.com/
[response_code] => 1
[scan_date] => 2013-06-10 21:19:32
[scan_id] => dd014af5ed6b38d9130e3f466f850e46d21b951199d53a18ef29ee9341614eaf-1370899172
[verbose_msg] => Scan finished, scan information embedded in this object
[filescan_id] => 
[positives] => 0
[total] => 39
[scans] => stdClass Object
    (
        [CLEAN MX] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [MalwarePatrol] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [ZDB Zeus] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [K7AntiVirus] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Quttera] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Yandex Safebrowsing] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [MalwareDomainList] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [ZeusTracker] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [zvelo] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Google Safebrowsing] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Kaspersky] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [BitDefender] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Opera] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [G-Data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [C-SIRT] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [CyberCrime] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => unrated site
            )

        [Sucuri SiteCheck] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [VX Vault] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [ADMINUSLabs] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [SCUMWARE.org] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Dr.Web] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [AlienVault] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Sophos] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => unrated site
            )

        [Malc0de Database] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [SpyEyeTracker] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Phishtank] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Avira] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Antiy-AVL] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Comodo Site Inspector] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => suspicious site
            )

        [Malekal] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [ESET] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [SecureBrain] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => unrated site
            )

        [Websense ThreatSeeker] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [Netcraft] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [ParetoLogic] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

        [URLQuery] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => unrated site
            )

        [Wepawet] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
                [detail] => 
            )

        [Fortinet] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => unrated site
            )

        [Minotaur] => stdClass Object
            (
                [detected] => 
                [result] => clean site
            )

    ) )
```

but i need a proper way of result using html and div like this

```
                                Results

URL=www.google.com 
 
Total Checking= 39                    
                                        Detected                  Result

1.  CLEAN MX                               0                    Clean site
2.  MalwarePatrol                          0                    Clean  site
3.  (E.X)……………………………………
```

please help me to complete my project.i would spend lots and lots of time to find a solution through the internet but there is a no solution for me. :-( :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats how you could loop and print out the data from your stdClass. You just sort this out with css if you want it prettier..

```
<table>
  <tr><td><?php echo $result->url; ?></td></tr>
  <tr><td><?php echo $result->total; ?></td></tr>
  <?php
  $none = 0;
  $i = 0;
  foreach($result->scans as $key => $val)
  {
      if($i==0) {
         echo '<th></th>';
         echo '<th></th>';
         echo '<th>Detected</th>';
         echo '<th>Result</th>';
      }
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'.intval($i+1).'.</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';

      if(empty($val->detected)): 
         echo '<td>'. $none .'</td>';
      else: 
         echo '<td>'. $val->detected .'</td>';
      endif; 

      echo '<td>'.$val->result.'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      $i++;
  }
  ?>
</table>
```

Comment: itz working thanks dude thanks a lot....! :-) :-) .i am doing some changes in above code that's all every thing perfect.